# Accessing a wordpress website container from a different machine does not display images?

Tags: networking, docker, wordpress

So I setup a wordpress website inside a docker container as on this [website](https://www.pattonwebz.com/docker/wordpress-docker-containers-production-images/). When I run docker compose the containers spin up just fine and I am able to access my wordpress website from the host machine's (ubuntu) browser by going to http://0.0.0.0:32768 - all good!

Issue is when I try accessing the website from another computer in the LAN.
I type the ip of the container host x.x.x.x:32768 and voila it loads the web page on this 2nd machine. But, the formatting and images on the website are all broken.When I hover over a broken image , it says the image location is 0.0.0.0:32768/wp-contents/a1.jpg

I try clicking on this link and it says website not found
Now I change the 0.0.0.0 to the ip address of the container host , x.x.x.x:32768/wp-contents/a1.jpg and it loads the image just fine!

So basically my question is how can I get the 2nd machine on the lan to consider all 0.0.0.0:32768 to be the container host ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!!

I just had to login into wordpress and then Go down to Settings > General 
From here I was able to set port and static ip( same as container host).

The website loads just fine on  the other machine within my lan network with all the images/formatting!